# How often can a specific zero-probability event occur in an infinite sequence independent realizations?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I'm trying to understand in a practical way the meaning of zero probability events.

Let's say that for a certain probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ we have an event $E \in \mathcal{F}: P(E)=0$

Now, let $X(\omega) = 1_E(\omega)$ be a binary variable defined over that space. Let $(X_i)_1^{\infty}$ be an infinite sequence of iid realizations of $X$ and $S = \sum_1^{\infty}X_i$ be an infinite sum of these iid variables.

What I want to understand is what can be said about $S$ for probability-zero events like $E$.

Since $E[X]=0$, then the SLLN implies that only a finite number of $X_i$ can be positive (via the SLLN). I.e., the tail event E="$X_i=0$ occurs finitely often" occurs with probability 1 [ more details below on my thinking here]

### Details on finiteness of iid sums of zero-probability events

One way think about a probability zero event $A$ is as the expected value of the indicator random variable $1_{A}$ defined on the unit square.

Let $X$ be a uniform random variable on the unit square. Then we have

$$E[1_A] = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_1^n 1_A(X_i) =0$$

So the *fraction* of times $A$ happens in an iid sequence converges almost surely to $0$. So if we kept taking larger and larger iid samples of $X$ we'd see $X_i \in A$ becomes a vanishingly small proportion of our sample.

Taking this one step further, consider the sum of the indicator functions:

$$S_n:= \sum_1^n 1_A(X_i)$$

Since the $1_A(X_i)$ are iid, we can invoke the [Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)
$$\text{Let $E_n$ be a sequence of events then} \sum_1^{\infty} P(E_n) < \infty \implies P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup E_n\right) = 0 \;\text{(i.e., a finite number of $E_n$ will occur, almost surely)}$$

to show that $$P\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n <\infty\right) = 1$$

*Proof*

$$P(1_{A}(X_i)=1)=0 \implies \sum_1^{\infty} P(1_{A}(X_i)=1) = 0 < \infty \implies P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup 1_{A}(X_i)\right) = 0$$

Which means that even in countably infinite samples you'd see $A$ only occur a finite number of times (almost surely -- still possible that you hit it infinitely often).

A similar conclusion is demonstrated in these two papers:

Lemma 3 (Page 4, item G) and the section right at the top of pdf page 5 which relates this to infinite sums of indicator variables: [https://viterbi-web.usc.edu/~mjneely/Borel-Cantelli-LLN.pdf](https://viterbi-web.usc.edu/%7Emjneely/Borel-Cantelli-LLN.pdf)

And corollary 2.3 here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2015/2dc1c9e37d402c000b628ee85e2228d1_MIT18_304S15_project2.pdf

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Andrew in an infinite sequence if iid probabiliyt-zero evens, how many do we expect to occur (not fraction, but count).

What is confusing about my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can say $S = 0$ almost surely.  Since $P(E)=0$, we have $P(X_i = 0) = 1$ for all $i$.  Thus
\begin{align*}
P(S = 0) &= P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \{X_i = 0\}\right) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^\infty P(X_i = 0) \tag{by independence} \\
&= 1
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! So more than just almost surely finite? This is a stronger result than I got. Where did I go wrong in my detailed analysis? Or did I just use a weaker condition (Borel-Cantelli) and didn't use the condition of independence (which seems to force the sum to 0 almost surely)?

Comment: @Annika Yes, you just used a weaker condition.  Independence isn't actually necessary, either, it just was the first way I thought of to show it.  In general, $P(S > 0) = P(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty \{X_i = 1\}) \le \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X_i = 1) = 0.$

Comment: oh, nice -- so its almost surely 0 no matter what :) thank you!